# Tomcat 6 doesn't see beans in jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jsf-2

After migration from JSF 1.2 to 2.1 tomcat doesn't see beans which are export to jar file. I export engine of application to jar for test and production server. If i copy class file to WEB-INF/clasess it works correct.

With JSF 1.2 this approach was working. There was using faces-bean.xml where was define all beans, now i use annotation and in faces-bean are only beans which i couldn't define using annotation.

I found in the Internet to add faces-config.xml, but i have it.

What can i do to force tomacat6 to see beans from jar file?

My config files:

**faces-confi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<component>
    <component-type>org.richfaces.OutputPanel</component-type>
    <component-class>my.package..UIOutputPanelWorkaround</component-class>
</component>
```

In web xml i have define few files with bean and navigation cases:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-config.xml,
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-beans-common.xml,
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-beans-admin.xml,
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-beans.xml,
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-navigations.xml,
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-navigations-admin.xml,      
        /WEB-INF/faces-config/faces-navigations-raports.xml
    </param-value>
```

Thanks!
regards

**UPDATE:**

One of exception which i found in log, myBean use annotations.

```
WARNING: #{myBean.page1}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /include/sprawdzSzanse-box-v2.xhtml @34,164 action="#{myBean.page1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: #{myBean.page1}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /include/sprawdzSzanse-box-v2.xhtml @34,164 action="#{myBean.page1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at my.package.LifecycleDecorator.execute(LifecycleDecorator.java:66)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at my.package.ie9fix.ie9fixFilter.doFilter(ie9fixFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /include/sprawdzSzanse-box-v2.xhtml @34,164 action="#{myBean.page1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
... 58 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /include/sprawdzSzanse-box-v2.xhtml @34,164 action="#{myBean.page1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 59 more
```

Comment: find this property name "page1" in your myBean.

Comment: property exist in myBean, I have this kind of exception for few more beans which use @ManagedBean annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I solved the problem. Previously I could not answer for too little reputation and i forgot about that.

I added to MATA-INF faces-config.xml which is placed in jar file with classes.

Contains of faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Sory for a late, i hope it  will help someone else.